# Duplication of mysql requests

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple php script with a query to the database (mysql):

```
<?php
mysql_query('SELECT NOW()');
?>
```

When I run this script (nginx/php-fpm)  through browsers such as Chrome or Opera in the mysql logfile there will be two records instead of one

```
141127 17:07:48 67 Connect  root@localhost on cms
           67 Query SELECT NOW()
           67 Quit  
           68 Connect   root@localhost on cms
           68 Query SELECT NOW()
           68 Quit
```

But when I run this script through Safari or console there will be only one record .

Can you explain why this is happening?

Comment: Is it possible your browser is fetching `favicon.ico` and that's getting handled by your PHP script? Check your browser's network requests.

Comment: check your http access log and see how many requests are coming in from the client. php itself wouldn't run the query twice on a single request.

Comment: ceejayoz, you're right! thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting my comment into an answer, this is often caused by your browser requesting `favicon.ico`. If you've got all requests going to `index.php` via a `.htaccess` file or something similar, this'll cause two requests on some pageviews.